# Django forms ModelChoiceField Use __Str__ or label_for_Instance and how?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Upon rendering ModelChoiceField as radio buttons in the template it returns `shareholder Object(2)` as opposed to data in the field name.

Somewhere in my view

```py
form.fields['shareholder'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                                  empty_label=None,
                                  queryset=ShareHolder.objects.filter(session_key=mykey),
                                  to_field_name="id",
                                  widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
                                  required=False
                                )
```

In my template

```html
{%  for sh in form.shareholder %}
  <div class="radio-group">{{ sh }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

my model is

```
class ShareHolder(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)

    # Person
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)

    # Company
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=False)
```

Now I could use the good old `__str__` function and I would get my values, but is there an alternative?

I tried to used to add the following in my forms file

```py
class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "My Object #%i" % obj.id
```

and then replace the view code with

```py
form.fields['shareholder'] = forms.MyModelChoiceField(
```

But when I run this it says module cannot find MyModelChoiceField.
Having said this I don't understand how the lable_form_instance works in the first place.

My fear with using `__str__` is that if I need to use the model another way then `__Str__` will need to be changed.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

i need to remove `forms.` from `forms.ModelChoiceField` in my code

with this in play i can now return any type of value for my modelchoice field